# Text mark-up for .csv output

Tags: text-editor

I have a lengthy text file containing words that are candidates for column headings and content for those columns ... Is there a tool that will let me mark a candidate word as "column heading" and then mark its associated content?  The rest of the text in the document can be ignored ...

I have the document in TextWrangler but outputting as .csv and importing into a spreadsheet (Numbers) results in a single column of undifferentiated text ... Transposing rows and columns doesn't solve the problem ... I'm trying to minimize editing the text before I output it as .csv (the overall goal is to import the .csv into SQLite) ...

I will be repeating this process with many such text documents, and while the documents are similar and the column headings once established probably won't change, the content will not line up uniformly row by row document to document ... Ideally, with a mark-up tool I would be able to define column headings and filter in content with minimal editing ...

This is how the text looks after I use Automator to extract it from .pdf: column headings read in vertically and some free-form text is "noise":

第五班 - 1200米 - (40-15)   場地狀況 :  好地至快地
心中有理讓賽  賽道 :    草地 - "B+2" 賽道
HK$ 600,000 時間 :    (23.67) (45.54) (1.09.54)
    分段時間 :  23.67   21.87   24.00
 全方位賽事重溫     餘勢分析     模擬鳥瞰重溫
名次  馬號  馬名  騎師  練馬師 實際
負磅  排位
體重  檔位  頭馬
距離  沿途
走位  完成
時間  獨贏
賠率
1   4   金磚五國(N443)  羅理雅 徐雨石 132 1132    2   -
9   7   1
1.09.54 10
2   2   永常喜(V107)   莫雷拉 李易達 132 1129    4   3/4 
2   1   2
1.09.65 3.6
3   9   齊齊健康(S320)  雷景勳 胡森  125 1096    11  1-3/4
14  12  3
1.09.82 17
4   10  正藍旗(S070)   黎海榮 霍利時 125 1082    7   2
12  9   4
1.09.87 82
5   12  天地福星(P064)  蘇狄雄 葉楚航 117 1033    6   2-3/4
5   4   5
1.09.98 36
6   14  勝捷勝(N156)   蔡明紹 吳定強 115 1063    3   4-3/4
10  8   6
1.10.30 12
7   5   快樂世紀(T042)  蔣嘉琦 告達理 123 1081    13  5-1/4
1   2   7
1.10.37 55
8   1   知道勝(S218)   潘頓  沈集成 133 1025    12  5-1/4
4   6   8
1.10.37 3
9   7   事必獲利(T002)  湯智傑 方嘉柏 126 1080    10  5-3/4
11  11  9
1.10.47 15
10  13  有料小子(S273)  田泰安 孫達志 118 1026    14  6-1/2
13  10  10
1.10.56 34
11  8   寶成駿星(T319)  鄭雨滇 何良  127 1055    8   6-3/4
3   3   11
1.10.60 11
12  6   勁飛駒(S350)   郭能  鄭俊偉 129 1276    1   8-3/4
6   5   12
1.10.94 10
13  3   有關係(V067)   寶遜  賀賢  132 1079    5   9-3/4
8   14  13
1.11.08 40
14  11  卓逸星(T404)   何澤堯 文家良 118 1030    9   15-1/4
7   13  14
1.11.99 99
備註: 賽事特別情況索引 
派彩
彩池  勝出組合    派彩 (HK$)
獨贏  4   102.50
位置  4   26.50
2   14.50
9   49.00
連贏  2,4 152.00
位置Q 2,4 56.50
4,9 204.50
2,9 109.00
3揀1（組合獨贏）
A1  未能勝出
A2  41.00
A3  未能勝出
詳情
三重彩 4,2,9   5,739.00
單T  2,4,9   1,048.00
四連環 2,4,9,10    8,871.00
四重彩 4,2,9,10    104,185.00

賽事沿途走位圖片

沿途走勢評述

競賽事件報告
「勁飛駒」出閘笨拙，起步緩慢。 「正藍旗」及「寶成駿星」躍出時均在「天地福星」與「卓逸星」之間受擠迫，
當時「天地福星」被「有關係」帶向外跑，而「卓逸星」則向內斜跑。 「有料小子」自大外檔出閘後於早段收慢。 
趨近千一米處時，「事必獲利」在「卓逸星」的後蹄外側處於窘境。 接近一千米處時，「有關係」於收慢以讓「天地福星」
（蘇狄雄）過頭時將頭轉側及向外斜跑。與此同時，「天地福星」在尚未充分帶離下向內移入。小組告誡蘇狄雄，必須確保已充分帶離後才可轉換跑線。 
見習騎師蔣嘉琦（「快樂世紀」）承認一項不小心策騎〔賽事規例第100(1)條〕，事緣在趨近八百米處時，她容許坐騎在尚未帶離「知道勝」時向內斜跑，
導致「知道勝」被帶向內跑橫越「卓逸星」應有的跑線，「卓逸星」因而踏著「知道勝」的後蹄及失蹄。見習騎師蔣嘉琦被罰款七萬元。 跟隨「卓逸星」的
「有關係」大力勒避該駒的後蹄，並且急促向外斜跑。賽後，「有關係」被發現左前腿有一個傷口。 接近一百五十米處時，「齊齊健康」向內移入避開
「快樂世紀」的後蹄。 跑過一百米處時，「有料小子」收慢避開「快樂世紀」的後蹄，當時「快樂世紀」向外斜跑。跟隨「有料小子」的「事必獲利」
向內移入避開該駒的後蹄，在末段將頭轉側。 「金磚五國」於直路上在催策下內閃。 「快樂世紀」沿途在外疊競跑，沒有遮擋。 賽後獸醫立即檢查「
知道勝」，內窺鏡檢查顯示該駒的氣管內有很多血。「知道勝」必須通過獸醫檢驗後，才可再次出賽。 賽後獸醫立即檢查「勁飛駒」，發現該駒左前腿不良於行。
「勁飛駒」必須通過獸醫檢驗後，才可再次出賽。 「知道勝」、「金磚五國」及「永常喜」均須抽取樣本檢驗。
勝出馬匹血統
金磚五國    父系: Good Journey 
母系: La Bayadere
若獲中之彩金為每十元一注超過五百萬元，所有中彩彩票持票人士或經由電話投注服務的中彩人士，包括使用智財咭、1886電話投注自動服務系統等，
請於指定時間致電本會1817登記。(使用互動投注服務途徑除外)

互動投注服務包括網上投注服務「投注區」、流動投注服務、Racing Touch流動應用程式、電訊運財寶豪華版/電訊運財寶綜合版及第八代投注寶。備註:
模擬鳥瞰重溫由特約供應商 Trakus提供，供馬迷作個人娛樂資訊之用。但由於香港馬場內手機信號頻繁，因此Trakus系統有可能受干擾而令模擬鳥瞰重溫片段出現偏差。
本會已盡一切努力務求有關資料盡可能準確，馬會就此並無責任。至於賽馬結果, 馬迷應參考實際的賽馬片段為準。

Comment: An example of the current text layout would be helpful - also what other tools are likely to need to support these files?

Comment: From your description, the importing application didn't understand the separators used by the exporting one. Make sure to find a match for those, and your issue is solved. However: this site doesn't do [howtos](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/882/185) or [manuals/tutorials](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1258/185), and your example output doesn't look like CVS – so I'm not sure your question fits here, or what kind of application we should recommend. But that might very well be due to my inability to read Chinese :)

Comment: Thank you ... The question is, how to prepare undifferentiated text for .csv output ...

Comment: Please edit your sample properly: indent it 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

I think some programming in Python needed here. For Python plugin for Sublime Text or CudaText.

You mark column head: plugin must count column number from it, and then place multi-selections, for all next lines. It must select all N-th column in those next lines. It is not easy to do.

Comment: Yes, I would use Python here, too.